# Can't get my code right

Tags: python

```
#this is my very first python attempt
#Getting the name
print ""
name = raw_input("Hello, adventurer. Before we get started, why don't you tell me your name.")
while name in (""):
    print "Sorry, I didn't get that."
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")

if len(name) > 0:
    print ""
    print "%s? Good name! I hope you are ready to start your adventure!" % name

#getting right or left
print ""
print "Well %s, we are going to head north along the river, so get a move on!" % name
print ""
question = "As you head out, you quickly come across a fork in the road.  One path goes right, the other goes left. Which do you chose: right or left?"
lor = raw_input(question).strip().lower()
while not "left".startswith(lor) and not "right".startswith(lor):
    print "That's not a direction."
    lor = raw_input(question).strip().lower()

if len(lor) > 0:
    if "left".startswith(lor):
        print "You went left"
    elif "right".startswith(lor):
        print "You went right"
else:
    print "That's not a direction."
    lor = raw_input(question).strip().lower()
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. When I run this code then it will ask `question`. as raw_input. If i don't put anything in, it correctly says "That's not a direction", and brings the question up a second time. However, the next time I put anything in, it comes up blank as an answer, no matter what I type in. Why is it not continually looping?

Comment: Can you edit your question so that what you are asking is more obvious? (Otherwise, the mods will likely close your question.)

Comment: `"left".startswith(lor)` should be the other way around: `lor.startswith('left')`. It probably makes more sense that way too.

Comment: Also, I've noticed you keep posting very similar questions and in each question you say "this is my first python attempt." Are you *certain* about that?

Comment: @blender that fixed the issue!   @ 2rs2ts I actually have that written in my code and am just copy/pasting the whole thing. It's the same code I'm trying to get right.

Comment: Now we just need @Blender to submit an official answer so that Rheanna can accept it and this question won't stay unanswered forever. ;)

Comment: Added answer as "community wiki"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `"left".startswith("")` will return True. So what's happening is that when you don't answer the first time, you end up breaking out of the while loop (because `"left"` starts with `""`) and going to the if/else.

At the if statement, the value of `lor` is `""` so you end up in the `else` fork. At that point the question gets asked again, but when the user responds, nothing is done with the new value of `lor`.

I would recommend editing your while loop to read:

```
while lor == "" or (not "left".startswith(lor) and not "right".startswith(lor)):
```

This way you only break out of the while loop if the answer starts with "left" or "right" and is NOT the empty string.

You should also get rid of the final `else` statement because it doesn't do anything useful :)

Comment: I like this solution better than the other suggested in the comments. Presumably, this would allow any substring of `'left'` to be used as an answer to the prompt, e.g. `'l'`

Answer (score 2):

`"left".startswith(lor)` should be the other way around: `lor.startswith('left')`
The same goes for `"right".startswith(lor)`.